# List of files into variables to pass into args of another

Tags: powershell

So I have a list of files in a folder I would like to use as arguments in a command to merge the files.

The syntax I need to end up with would look like this:

```
python runcommand.py Arg1 Arg2 Arg3 Arg4 Arg5 Arg6.txt
```

arg1-5 are the filename lists.

Struggling with the best approach to do this.  Not sure I'm going about it in the best way.  Seems like I should be able to `gci -rec FolderLocation` and get some variables from there then call on the Python script from within same PowerShell script?

Comment: I’m not sure I can follow. Are you sure that there is always 5 (or is it 6) files in the directory or that the python script can take any number of files, or should the solution call the python script multiple times with 5 (or is it 6) in each?

Comment: python script can take any number of files.  the last argument "arg6.txt" would not be in the file list.  just coded with a variable.

Comment: What's wrong on `python runcommand.py (gci -rec FolderLocation).FullName Arg6.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

Treating the last item in a list of unnamed arguments differently from the rest of the unnamed arguments is bad interface design. If a particular argument has a specific purpose: make it a named parameter.

```python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', metavar='output', help='Output file.')
parser.add_argument('file', nargs='+', help='Input files.')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then you can run this in PowerShell:

```bsh
$files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' -Recurse
& python runcommand.py -o 'C:\path\to\output.txt' $files
```

However, why use a script in a different language in the first place, when all you have to do for concatenating files in PowerShell is something like this?

```bsh
Get-ChildItem 'C:\some\folder' -Recurse | Where-Object {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer
} | Get-Content | Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.txt'
```